# convert a text file contain data in binary representation (only 0&1) to .bin file in python

Tags: python, file, riscv, bin

I have a text file contains only zeros and ones each 32 bits in one line here is a sample :

```
00001111110000010000010100010111
00000010000001010000010100010011
00000000100000000000010110010011
00000000000000000000001100010111
```

I want to convert this file to .bin file using python , I have searched I saw people converting from data to bin file but this ffile is already zeros and ones.

thank you all.

Comment: So you are expecting that first line to output 0x0FC10517?  (with or without the 0x or uppercase or lower, doesnt matter that is not my question 0fc10517)

Comment: you selected a high level solution did you also want to solve it generically and not language library specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse a string to an integer treating the string as a number written in binary using [`int`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/functions.html#int):

```
integers = [
    int(line, 2)
    for line in your_file
]
```

In your case, `integers` will be `[264307991, 33883411, 8390035, 791]`. Then retrieve their binary representation with [`int.to_bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/stdtypes.html#int.to_bytes):

```
>>> [i.to_bytes(4, 'little') for i in integers]
[b'\x17\x05\xc1\x0f', b'\x13\x05\x05\x02', b'\x93\x05\x80\x00', b'\x17\x03\x00\x00']
```

Then write these bytes to the other file:

```
with open("file.bin", "wb") as out:
    for i in integers:
        out.write(i.to_bytes(4, 'little'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can open the text file for reading and then create a binary file for writing using the open() function. Then you create a byte array from the text file (encoded for utf8) and write it to the binary file.

```
with open("binary.txt", "r") as textfile:
    with open("binary.bin", "w+b") as binfile:
        binfile.write(bytearray(textfile.read(), 'utf8'))
```